# How register click action on dropdown menu with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having some trouble with JQuery Mobile. I have a dropdown menu, and when I select an option from the menu, I can successfully get JQuery to print out a console statement. I have a link to another page that has the same dropdown menu with the same id as the previous page. When I select an option from that, then I cannot get JQuery to print a console statement for me. How do I get JQuery to print a console statement for me in this case?

There is basically a header on every page with a dropdown menu, but it only works when the page is initially loaded. If a user clicks a link to another page with the same dropdown menu, it stops working even though the dropdown menus have the same ID

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var courseID = $("#course_id").attr('value');
    var holeNum = $("#hole_number").attr('value');
    $("#score-dropdown").click(function() {
        console.log(courseID);
        console.log(holeNum);
    });
})
```

One way to fix this is adding `data-ajax="false"` to my links, but then I am unable to see a swipe animation. Is there anyway around this?

**Edit:** I figured out why. I have to change the code to the following:

```
$("#score-dropdown").live('change', function() {
    var courseID = $("#course_id").attr('value');
    var holeNum = $("#hole_number").attr('value');
    console.log(courseID);
    console.log(holeNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no other scripts failing on the other pages.

Comment: Hello, I think the problem is that when you click a link with JQuery Mobile, it loads the link using AJAX. So, something messes up when I do that.